# Split a <UL><LI> into 4 columns?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using Jinga templating language and bootstrap 4 with my Django application.  I'm looking to display the following list of application in multiple columns instead of one.  How could I split this list into 4 columns?

```
<div class = "container">



      <h2>Available Application List</h2>

<ul>

        {% for app in applicationlist %}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="..." >  {{ app.report_name }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap, check out the equal distribution columns that are available via the `col` class: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width

Hope that helps!

Comment: How could I use this with my for loop?

Comment: Very similarly to what you're doing now except instead of the <li> use a <div class="col"> to tap into Bootstrap 4s column structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS for this. Try a multi-column layout:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

Other solutions would include using `display: flex` on the parent `<ul>`, setting percentage widths on each `<li>` along with `float: left`, or using `display: inline-block` on each `<li>`.

Comment: How would you implement this in the for loop?

Comment: This solution wouldn't require any changes to your loop or HTML output. It would require changing the site's CSS. If you want a solution that doesn't touch CSS, use @Steve Frost 's solution.